# Eclipse does not recognize examplefilefinder

Tags: java, swing

I have been trying to set up a java Filechooser.

However, even the coding fragment from

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html

does not work, because eclipse does not seem to know what to do with the ExampleFileFinder.

Eclipse does not recognize it.

Is there an obvious mistake in the fragment?

Comment: Yes, it's outdated by several years and Java versions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this. is more actual as java 1.4

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html